# How to Define USB Port as a Stable Name on Raspberry PI 3B+

Tags: pi-3b+

[image]In my Pi,
on the `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` file

- ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="USB4", ATTRS{devpath}=="1.5"
- ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="USB1", ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2"
- ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="USB2", ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
- ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="USB3", ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4"

I write above file parameters, but on my older pi 3, its is working properly. but on pi 3b+ isn't working.
I need help regarding this.

Comment: Does this help? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135927/moved-from-main-stack-overflow-udev-rules-not-working-with-rasberry-pi-teensy/135930

Comment: Using ATTRS{devpath} might assign by physical port, but may not be stable.  It would be better to use some other (unique) attribute, like serial number.

Comment: Thanks for Your Reply. I solve the mention Problem. This Propblem is only because of TYPE of RASPBERRY PI. Firstly I used the Raspberry Pi 3B and now I am using Raspberry Pi 3B+ Module. And only because of This it will gives a Problem. Thans for Support